# TikZ edges to/from center of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Normally an edge drawn between two nodes starts and stops at the boundary of the nodes.  How can one draw an edge to the center of a node?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Current result:

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (0)              {};
  \node (1) [right of=0] {};
  \node (2) [above right of=1] {};
  \draw (0) -- (1);
  \draw (1) -- (2);
 \end{tikzpicture}

Desired result (looks like):

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw (1,0) -- (1.5,.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want my TikZ code to be readable, so I first place the nodes with relative positions and then draw the edges. I created the desired result without using the relative placement of nodes. This is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can suffix an anchor to any node:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Current result:

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (0)              {};
  \node (1) [right of=0] {};
  \node (2) [above right of=1] {};
  \draw (0.center) -- (1.center);
  \draw (1.center) -- (2.center);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful. I knew the answer should be simple. Thanks!